# SQL Server compare varbinary columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a project at hand which uses SQL Server to store fingerprints bitmap from a terminal hand held fingerprint reader.

My question: is there a way of comparing the fingerprint match in the database instead of bringing back all the fingerprints from the database for authentication?

Something like a query eg

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE fingerprintcolumn = fingerprint_template
```

Comment: You can compare varbinary columns with the normal equality operator, exactly as you have it written in the question. [Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0d40a8dc1dd56d6645ceed9555d9f683). This will only work for an exact match, I expect that fingerprint matching is significantly more complex than this, and not something that could be handled within SQL Server

Comment: Will this actually be useful? The fingerprint scanners I worked with didn't allow simple equals comparison - the values from two subsequent scans of the same finger were different, and you had to compare them with a special match function that also included configuration for how similar the prints have to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do the comparison with simple compare/= operator. In the the reality, when you get the same fingerprint two times, both the images will be different from each other with little bit position change, angle change, and quality of the scan. So String comparison is not possible.

You have to get your automated fingerprint identification system implemented or need to get the 3rd party fingerprint comparison services like one from [Cams Fingerprint Comparison API](https://camsunit.com/application/javascript-based-fingerprint-scanner-for-website-authentication-and-attendance.html#compare-fingerprint)